# C# Entity framework with relation OneToMany

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I use the Entity framework with MVC 5 (C#). I have a relation oneToMany with my user entity and a post entity. My users can contain many Post.

I have the code:

```
    public User getUser(String login)
    {
        ProjectEntities db = new ProjectEntities();
        var query = (from User in db.Users
                    where User.Login == login
                    select User);
        if (query.Count() == 0)
            return null;
        return query.FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public function anotherMth() {
            var user = auth.getUser(login);
            ProjectEntities db = new ProjectEntities ();
            Post p = db.Posts.OrderByDescending(c => c.ID).FirstOrDefault();
            Post post = new Post() { 
                User = user,
                ID = (null == p ? 0 : p.ID) + 1
            };
            user.Posts.Add(post);
            db.Users.Attach(user);
            db.Entry(user).Property(e => e.Posts).IsModified = true;
            db.SaveChanges();
     }
```

The error is: "An entity object can not be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker"

Comment: What does auth.getUser do? Is the user that it returns already tracked by another DbContext?

Comment: I added the code. I think my user is already track by the DbContext. How can i get my user and add a Post ?

Comment: I tend not to worry about assigning an ID, entity framework takes care of this and i think this might be your problem.

Comment: Are you sure you need to update `user`? You don't seem to be modifying any user properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get the user, you can get it without tracking by using the AsNoTracking extension method...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj556203.aspx